# Progress Dialog in Thread NullPointer Exception

Tags: android

Hi i have a fragment and when i call it from my MainActivity i start a Thread to show somethings of BD

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        if ( args != ) 
        {
            progressDialog.show( getActivity(), "Query", "Please wait", true, false );
            // Here i call my thread
            mRutFechas( progressDialog );
        }
    }
```

my thread

```
private void mRutFechas( final ProgressDialog progressDialog )
{
        Thread nt = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Lot of BD Conecction work

                 // Display
                 getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                 {
                     @Override
                     public void run()
                     {
                         // Screen update
                     }
                 });
              progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        nt.start();
}
```

The popup show propertly but when its time to close to display throw

```
03-12 11:52:29.132  25504-25618/com.example.camilo.relojcontrol_navdraw E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9962
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.camilo.relojcontrol_navdraw.F_RelojMostrar$2.run(F_RelojMostrar.java:301)
```

EDIT: When i put in run UI Thread it gives me this error

```
03-12 12:20:09.652  27235-27235/com.example.camilo.relojcontrol_navdraw E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.camilo.relojcontrol_navdraw.F_RelojMostrar$2$1.run(F_RelojMostrar.java:300)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should use AsyncTask

Comment: put `progressDialog.dismiss();` inside of `run()` method of `runOnUiThread` as last line.

Comment: Post complete stacktrace (error log).

Comment: edited the error log

Comment: Which one is code line 300 in `F_RelojMostrar.java`?

Comment: its the `progressDialog.dismiss();` in the UI Thread at last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProgressDialog progressDialog;` is **NULL** in `mRutFechas()`

Because `show()` method will create a ProgresssDialog as a **static**.

Try to change it with

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
 public void onStart()
 {
  super.onStart();
  Bundle args = getArguments();
  if ( args != ) 
   {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Query");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();

    // Here i call my thread
    mRutFechas(progressDialog);
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: yes, i forgot to initalize as you said `ProgressDialog progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);` now its not null but inside the thread i cant put the code `  progressDialog.dismiss();` because compiler says `Error:(299, 25) error: local variable progressDialog is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final` so if i make the declaration of my method to static variable `private void mRutFechas( final ProgressDialog progressDialog )` the popup show up in the screen but doesnt close and keep showing forever .- ty for feedback

Comment: @Junshi - Is it the last line in runOnUiThread()'s `run()`? It should be there. And declare `ProgressDialog progressDialog` as class level member above code only for your understanding. in `onStart()` it looks like `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());`.

Comment: yes its at last of UI run thread , this its getting a liitle tricky, may i try async task ?

Answer (score 0):

Main Thread is also known as **UI Thread**. That means you cannot update any UI in any other thread but Main Thread. So you can't dismiss the ProgressDialog in background thread. Just put it in main thread and everything would be fine.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: running in UI Thread give me 03-12 12:20:09.652  27235-27235/com.example.camilo.relojcontrol_navdraw E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException Check the main post i edited the error log

Comment: idk why i get nullpointer exception, maybe if i try with async task ?

Comment: It is obviously that progressDialog variable is null. Please try to do step debugging and see that is it really null and why.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize your progress dialog:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Mainactivity.this);
```